# how to insert text into a field without id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i'm trying to use the following code to insert test into a field without id

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#insert").click(function(){
        $("#gfield_list_cell gfield_list_356_cell2").val("TEST");
    });
});
```

```html
<td class="gfield_list_cell gfield_list_356_cell2" data-label="FIRST"><input type="text" name="input_356[]" value="" tabindex="14"></td>

<p><input id="insert" name="test" type="button" value="test" /></p>
```

Comment: Java is NOT Javascript, I think you got confused about it

Comment: That's not an `id` value, it's a `class` value.  Use the *class* selector: `$(".gfield_list_cell gfield_list_356_cell2")`  It's also worth noting that a `<td>` element doesn't have a "value".  What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

your selector is ID selector, not a CLASS selector

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#insert").click(function(){
      $(".gfield_list_cell gfield_list_356_cell2").val("TEST");
  });
});
```

should work.

or if you want to change the value of the INPUT TYPE="text" you should do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#insert").click(function(){
      $(".gfield_list_cell gfield_list_356_cell2").children().val("TEST");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#insert").click(function(){
        $("#testing").val("TEST");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<td class="gfield_list_cell" data-label="FIRST"><input id="testing" type="text" name="input_356[]" value="" tabindex="14"></td>

<p><input id="insert" name="test" type="button" value="test" /></p>
```

Comment: my td class have no id

Comment: you can not put value in td,
you can put value in any input field i have changed it and given id to input field, you can check code snippet.run the snippet.

Comment: If it helps you and solved your problem then mark answer as right answer or       give it a upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by specifying the classes of your `td` tag and the input field inside it, to be more specific (considering you do not have any other input inside the td).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#insert").click(function() {
    $(".gfield_list_cell.gfield_list_356_cell2").children("input").val("TEST");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="gfield_list_cell gfield_list_356_cell2" data-label="FIRST"><input type="text" name="input_356[]" value="" tabindex="14"></td>
  </tr>
  <table>
    <p><input id="insert" name="test" type="button" value="test" /></p>
```

I hope this helps you.

Good luck.

Comment: Great!

Can you please mark my answer as the right one then? Thank you.

Comment: @privacymx, please mark my answer as the right one as it worked for you. Thank you.